# What mint is there growing in my garden?

Tags: identification, mint

Can you help me identify the three mint plants growing in my garden?

[image]

The left has purple stems and a bit furry leaves that are thicker than the middle.

On the right the leaves are distinctly spiky.

When I bought them in pots in the supermarket the labels very helpfully said "mint".

Location: central Germany.

Thank you all!